# Can i use Javascript in XSL while converting an XML to another XML?

Tags: xml

I've an XML document and I am creating another XML using XSL. I need to check some specific conditions and for that I want to use Javascript in my XSL. I tried it, however, couldn't get the desired result. 
I am not sure whether the Javascript will work in this XSL for checking the conditions or not.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT are XML transformation files. They are run via an XSLT transform engine. The only way I can see that javascript would work.. is if the XSLT transform engine understood Javascript somehow. I wouldn't expect it to. Which XSL transformation engine are you using?

**Update:** maybe this will help http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26881&seqNum=4

Note in this article he references a specific transformation engine (Xalan-Java 2 XSLT). Each one is open to implement extensions like this differently.

Comment: Thanks for the link Nigel, I tried with that as well, however, got the following error- "org.apache.xalan.extensions.ObjectFactory$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not found".
I am not sure that which XALAN Version I am using, not even sure that which XSLT processor it is using. where could i find all these informations? I am running it on IBM RAD 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

In Mozilla it seems an object is supplied to do just that: check, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations . (Below are some code excerpts from the MDC documentation).

You will need to specify a *XSLT stylesheet* and then create a `XSLTProcessor` object:

```
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
```

Doing that you may implement a new document and transform it according to the XSLT style specified:

```
var testTransform = document.implementation.createDocument("", "test", null);  
    testTransform.addEventListener("load", onload, false);  
    testTransform.load("test-transform.xml");  

    function onload() {  
        processor.importStylesheet(testTransform);  
    }
```

HTH,

FK